# Multi-QComboBox Hide/Show Popup on LineEdit Press (PyQT5)

Tags: pyqt5, popup, qcombobox, qlineedit

I have created a checkable QComboBox where all the options are checkboxes. Everything works fine, except I can no longer click on the QLineEdit to open/close the combobox pop-up, the way a regular QComboBox would work.

I have tried to apply an event filter to the QLineEdit, as shown below, that should ideally close the combobox pop-up if it is currently open, and open it if it is currently closed. But instead, clicking on QLineEdit only opens the pop-up everytime.

I believe this is because the mouse button press (QEvent.MouseButtonPress) closes the pop-up (hence setting the self.isPopup boolean to False), so the mouse button release (QEvent.MouseButtonRelease) will always open the pop-up. I've tried to get the QCombobox to ignore the MouseButtonPress event, but to no avail. I'm not sure where I've gone wrong here - if anyone has any suggestions, it would be much appreciated.

(Here's the relevant parts of the code)

```
class CustomComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomComboBox, self).__init__()
        self.setModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)) # setting up widget to make it checkable
        self.setEditable(True)
        self.lineEdit().setReadOnly(True)
        self.lineEdit().setPlaceholderText("--Select Option--")

        self.isPopup = False  # bool to close or open pop up 

        self.lineEdit().installEventFilter(self)  # event filter for lineedit presses

    def hidePopup(self):
        super().hidePopup()
        self.isPopup = False

    def showPopup(self):
        super().shwoPopup()
        self.isPopup = True

    def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
        if widget == self.lineEdit():
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
                if self.isPopup:
                    self.hidePopup()
                else:
                    self.showPopup()
                return True
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
                event.ignore()
                return True
        return super(CustomComboBox, self).eventFilter(widget, event)
```

Comment: Remove `self.lineEdit().setReadOnly(True)`, as it doesn't make any sense for an *editable* combo box.

Comment: @musicamante it's not an editable combobox. I have to make it editable in order to modify the lineEdit text programmatically (through setText and setPlaceholderText) but I don't want the user to be able to edit it. Hence setReadOnly(True).

Comment: The problem is that doing so you're relying on the lineedit to handle button events, which become "out of scope" of the main combo box event handling. The main issue is that the combo is closed when the mouse is *pressed*, so `hidePopup` is invoked before the button is released. Since your requirement is to "write" custom text (which, btw, you didn't specify in your question), you should instead override the paintEvent.

Comment: The code in the question works exactly as expected. In fact, the `isPopup` stuff isn't needed. Replacing it with `if self.view().isVisible()` works fine as well. For me, the view receives the focus when the popup is opened, so the line-edit doesn't receive the subsequent mouse-release event. Is there some other code you're not showing that somehow causes the view to lose the focus? What platform are you testing on? Please provide a proper [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that making the combo editable, you actually have *two* widgets that can handle mouse events, and since QComboBox handles mouse buttons in a specific way (to allow proper popup management) that makes things difficult, because the popup normally closes after the button *press*.

Since your requirement for the editable line edit is just to write custom text, then just override the `paintEvent` by slightly changing the default behavior:

```py
class CustomComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    customText = ''
    def setCustomText(self, text):
        if self.customText != text:
            self.customText = text
            self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if not self.customText:
            super().paintEvent(event)
            return
        painter = QStylePainter(self)
        painter.setPen(self.palette().color(QPalette.Text))
        opt = QStyleOptionComboBox()
        self.initStyleOption(opt)
        painter.drawComplexControl(QStyle.CC_ComboBox, opt)
        opt.text = self.customText
        painter.drawControl(QStyle.CE_ComboBoxaLabel, opt)
```

With the code above, you don't need to make the combo editable, and therefore there is no event filtering.

Comment: thanks so much! I hadn't considered paintEvent at all, thank you for pointing me in the right direction :)